# How to add WebRTC functionality in android app

Tags: android, video-streaming, webrtc

How can I easily add WebRTC functionality to my android app so that I would be able to play video stream in [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)?

1. **What library (`.jar` file) do I have to add to referencies?**
2. **Could you add some code example please?**

Comment: @Busky did you able to create the android app by using webrtc?Is it possible?Please do share some knowledge.I want to create an application with webrtc for android application

Comment: I wasnt able to use it due to lack of usable examples on internet ...

Comment: @Busky Same issue i am facing.There is lack of webrtc example in internet.Also i tried to create it by myself.but it i get stop when i come to socket and netwroking code

Comment: Hope this will help you a lot to get better intuition:

https://github.com/mail2chromium/Android-Native-Development-For-WebRTC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, there is no such ".jar" files for you to reference right now.

WebRTC is designed for web browsers, even if it can be build for android and iOS.

for your question, I think you may need to learn how to build WebRTC on Android or iOS.

for Android, you should know [NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) and [JNI](http://www.steveolyo.com/JNI/JNI.html) first. then build whole webrtc projects or standalone VoE\ViE even NS\AECM\VAD\AGC modules for android.

for iOS, you should also build it by yourself, but you may need [this](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/04/using-open-source-static-libraries-in-xcode-4/) help.

all of these info can be found on the internet, especially [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/discuss-webrtc).

Answer (score 2):

checkout following link : http://www.webrtc.org/reference/getting-started
I have added my project on github: https://github.com/SDkie/Webrtc-for-Android, you can fork and make changes in it.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/android.

It has all the information on how to build webRTC for android.

The java wrapper for the native webRTC libraries:
https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/trunk/talk/app/webrtc/java/#java%2Fsrc%2Forg%2Fwebrtc

It has the instructions on how to build the native libraries.

It also has an example app that uses webRTC to talk to the https://apprtc.appspot.com.

https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/trunk/webrtc/examples/android/media_demo/README

I could not find instructions on how to create an Android Studio Project and build it with gradle though. If anyone finds it, please share.
I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the crosswalk, you can create a native app using the crosswalk as a webview in your project.

In my case the Web-RTC worked without any problems.

Here are some tutorials on how to add the crosswalk on your project.

https://diego.org/2015/01/07/embedding-crosswalk-in-android-studio/

https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/embedding_crosswalk.html

I hope this helps.